Is there a way to create foreign keys at runtime in Entity Framework?
For background, let's say I have two classes:
public class OrderType1 : ModelBase 
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
}

public class OrderType2 : ModelBase 
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
}

Then one class that can hold a reference to either of these types, based on a base class ModelBase which does not have the Customer field in it.
public class ScheduledOrder : ModelBase 
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ClientId))]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public int OrderType { get; set; }
    public int? TemplateId { get; set; }

    // This can be either OrderType1 or OrderType2
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TemplateId))]
    public Virtual ModelBase Template { get; set; } 
}

I want to be able to include Template when I retrieve a ScheduledOrder from the database so that I can access the Customer field of either class, and maybe do specific things with each derived class.
When I attempt this I get errors in OnConfiguring of a completely different type and it looks unrelated.
My question is is something like this even possible? I want to avoid having to query the database again using an OrderType property or something.

And how is the ScheduledOrder modelled in the database? Does it have two template fields where one of them is  NULL?

ScheduledOrder just has the one TemplateId, I was hoping for this ID field to reference a different table depending on the orderType instantiated with it since orderType1 and orderType2 are contained in different tables.

Why you can't move Customer to ModelBase?

I want to be able to do different things depending on whether a ScheduledOrder contains orderType1 or orderType2. I could move Customer over but the other fields that are specific to the orderType I can't move over.

Sounds kind of weird, even outside of the EF thing. You will need to do a lot of casting on every move you make?

@siggemannen I have all of these objects hooked up to repositories, so the alternative is calling the database again based on an OrderType enum, which means I would have to make the orderType1 and orderType2 service available for ScheduledOrders. I would rather just cast a few times.
